# How to create an app with a GMail-like layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

Would be possible to extend this kind of layout so that I can have a list of voices on the left of the screen and on the right I have a form that changes with the voice I select? For instance, if I press on "user data" it will show me a form with name, surname, buttons to change, etc, while if I press on "works" it would show me all work related buttons and data.

Comment: It would be much better if you provided a picture or scheme of what you wanted to get.

Comment: Are you talking something about like [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html)?

Comment: Yes, thanks, I didn't know at all about fragments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you might be looking for something like this.

http://www.linuxforu.com/2011/05/android-fragments-api/